# SQL to fetch today as well as yesterday records in a single row

Tags: mysql

We have a `log` table which consists of the columns: `job name,start time,end time, status,source count, target count,reject count,error count` etc.

Each record will consist of info about each job.
My result should like `job name,start dt,end dt, status,source count, target count,reject count,error count(Today entry),source count, target count,reject count,error count(yesterday count)`

We need to have the record count for today as well as today in a single row.
we are currently fetching the records using the below query.

```
select * from logtable where start dt=current_date
```

Can anyone help me with SQL to get the above result.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is very hard to understand - 'today as well as today'... It is very important for this question to give the data type of Date columns - is it DATE ot DATETIME. Better write the CREATE TABLE query for your table.

Comment: sorry..its today as well as yesterday.

Comment: start_dt,end_dt are timestamp columns

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new anser based on your updates:

```
select  logToday.`job name`,
        logToday.`start time`,
        logToday.`end time`, 
        logToday.status,
        logToday.`source count`,
        logToday.`target count`,
        logToday.`reject count`,
        logToday.`error count`,
        logYesterday.`source count`, 
        logYesterday.`target count`,
        logYesterday.`reject count`,
        logYesterday.`error count`
from logtable logToday
join logtable logYesterday on logYesterday.`start time` = subdate(current_date, 1)
where logToday.`start time` = current_date;
```

The above should work for you.
You say theat the columns is named "start time" but in the select you use "start dt"?

Old answer:

If you just want the two rows from today and yesterday on the same rows you can do it like this:

```
select logToday.*, logYesterday.*
from logtable logToday
join logtable logYesterday on logYesterday.startdt = subdate(current_date, 1)
where logToday.startdt = current_date;
```

If i missed something please provide some more info and i will modify the answer.

Comment: Do you know what a mess will happen if you run this query? I'm not sure if ever MySQL will execute it. You join a table to the same table based on very strange criteria... The result column names will overlap...

Comment: The tables are actually not joined it just picks one row per table and its suppose to overlap, thats why alias are used. If you want column with name logname just use logToday.logname or logYesterday.logname to seperate them. But if i am missing something i always love to be corrected so I can learn something new.